# concat all distinct value of several columns into a column in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, concatenation

I have a dataset like this :

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | e | i |
| b | f | j |
| c | g | k |
| d | h | l |

I want to obtain this :

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | e | i | a b c d e f g h i j k l |
| b | f | j | a b c d e f g h i j k l |
| c | g | k | a b c d e f g h i j k l |
| d | h | l | a b c d e f g h i j k l |

Do you know how to do this in python Pyspark ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `window` function and then use `array_sort,flatten` functions with `collect_set`.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *
w=Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df2= df.withColumn("temp_c1",collect_set(col("c1")).over(w))\
  .withColumn("temp_c2",collect_set(col("c2")).over(w))\
  .withColumn("temp_c3",collect_set(col("c3")).over(w))\
  .withColumn("c4",array_join(array_distinct(sort_array(flatten(array(col("temp_c1"),col("temp_c2"),col("temp_c3"))))),'')).\
    drop(*['temp_c1','temp_c2','temp_c3'])

df2.show(10,False)
#+---+---+---+------------+
#|c1 |c2 |c3 |c4          |
#+---+---+---+------------+
#|b  |f  |j  |abcdefghijkl|
#|c  |g  |k  |abcdefghijkl|
#|d  |h  |l  |abcdefghijkl|
#|a  |e  |i  |abcdefghijkl|
#+---+---+---+------------+
```